# How to get a json object with specific key values, from a json array column?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, object

In my MySQL 8.0 table, I have a JSON ARRAY column. It is an array of JSON objects. I want to pick one object out of each row's array, based on the key value pairs in the objects.

Example row:

```
[{bool:false, number:0, value:'hello'}, 
{bool:true, number:1, value:'world'},
{bool:true, number:2, value:'foo'},
{bool:false, number:1, value:'bar'}]
```

What I am trying to do is get the 'value' WHERE bool=true, AND number=1. So I want a query that in this example returns 'world'.

What would also work is if I could get the index of the object where bool=true and number=1, in this example it would return '$[1]'.

I am trying to run a query across the whole column, setting a new column to the value returned from the query. Is this possible with MySQL JSON functions? I've looked at the references but none have objects inside arrays like my example.

EDIT: If I do

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(column->"$[*]", 'all', '1');
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(names->"$[*]", 'all', 'true');
```

I get the paths/indexes of objects where number=1, and where bool=true, respectively. I would like the overlap of these two results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to convert the JSON into a derived table which you can then extract values from:

```
SELECT j.value
FROM test t
JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.jsonStr, 
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS(bool BOOLEAN PATH '$.bool',
                number INT PATH '$.number',
                value VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.value')) j                    
WHERE j.bool = true AND j.number = 1
```

Output:

```
value
world
```

If you *also* want to get the index within each JSON value of the `value` which matched, you can add a `FOR ORDINALITY` clause to your `JSON_TABLE` e.g.:

```
SELECT j.idx, j.value
FROM test t
JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.jsonStr, 
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS(idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                bool BOOLEAN PATH '$.bool',
                number INT PATH '$.number',
                value VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.value')) j
WHERE j.bool = true AND j.number = 1
```

Output:

```
idx     value
2       world
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e9cf8470fd75de3a5cd6f823c9fd068)

Comment: Thank you! This worked and your examples were very helpful

Comment: THe above  code runs successfully only on Mysql 8.0 though. What about greater than mysql 5.7  and less than mysql 8.0

Comment: @rdkrosan If you mean for versions 8.0.1 to 8.0.3 (which don't support JSON_TABLE), you would need to use the same solution as you would use for 5.7. If you need such a solution, you should ask a question.